# Is it possible to get the versionName without the suffix from Android?

Tags: android, gradle, version

Consider `app.gradle`includes the following:

```
    defaultConfig {
       versionName "2.1.6"
    }
    debug {
        debuggable true
        versionNameSuffix "-debug"
    }
```

Is it possible to get the version name without the suffix? When using `PackageInfo pInfo = applicationContext.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(applicationContext.getPackageName(), 0);`

`pInfo.versionName` returns `2.1.6-debug` is there a way to get only `2.1.6` without doing some string or regex matching.

Thank you!

Comment: why not simply `pInfo.versionName.replace("-debug","")`?

Comment: Or, use a Gradle constant, used to populate both a `buildConfigField` and your `versionName`. AFAIK, the un-suffixed version name is not available.

Comment: You know that "versionNameSuffix" is optional, isn't it?

Comment: versionNameSuffix is optional but I want to have multiple versions, also 2.1.6-staging.

Answer (score 13):

I would do it using generated `BuildConfig`:

**Gradle**

```
defaultConfig {
  def version = "2.1.6"
  versionName version
  buildConfigField "String", "VERSION", "\"$version\""
}
```

**Java**

```
String version = BuildConfig.VERSION;
```

Answer (score 3):

Question is old, but it might help someone - I have looked for something similar recently and used this:

```
debug{
     buildConfigField "String", "APP_VER", "\"" + android.defaultConfig.versionName + "\""
}
```

OR for all buidTypes

```
buildTypes.each {
       it.buildConfigField "String", "APP_VER", "\"" + android.defaultConfig.versionName + "\""
}
```

OR for all app variants:

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.buildConfigField "String", "APP_VER", "\"" + android.defaultConfig.versionName + "\""
}
```